# Two root elements automatically create while building the app using webpack and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx, html-webpack-plugin

I am building the website using React and compiling it using babel and webpack. I am using `html-webpack-plugin` to create html files on compiling using webpack. But the `root` element is created twice once the file is rendered.

**HTML file after rendering by webpack.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Far-Away</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="crx-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0mnQ.png)

the following are the files that are used to build the project.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = [
  {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    target: "web",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "bundle.[contenthash].js",
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "./src/index.html",
      }),
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.jpg$/,
          type: "asset/resource",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

**index.html in the src folder.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Far-Away</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.js file**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Logo />
      <Form />
      <PackingList />
      <Stats />
    </div>
  );
}

function Logo() {
  return <h1 className="h1">Far Away</h1>;
}

function Form() {
  return (
    <div className="add-form">
      <h3 className="h3">What do you need for your trip?</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

function PackingList() {
  return <div className="list">LIST</div>;
}

function Stats() {
  return <footer className="stats"></footer>;
}
```

**index.js file**

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.js";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

**index.html in the dist folder which is created by html-webpack-plugin**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Far-Away</title>
  <script defer src="bundle.810e2640f2598054fc60.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do check out the github repo: https://github.com/rakshithvk19/far-away